# MongoDB: aggregate multiple fields to make a total

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like these:

```
{
    "_id": "UniqueOrderID",
    "date": ISODate("2019-06-29T13:49:51Z"),
    "margherita": 3,
    "hawaii": 2,
    "diavolo": 4,
    "quattro_formaggi": 2
}
```

And I want to create a document like this:

```
{
    "_id": "UniqueOrderID",
    "date": ISODate("2019-06-29T13:49:51Z"),
    "pizzas": 11
}
```

So: can I add the fields's values from "margherita", "hawaii", "diavolo" and "quattro_formaggi" to the field "pizzas" (to become 11, in this example)? And if, how to do that?

Comment: Have you checked out [$sum](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)?

Comment: Yeah. But how does that work with multiple field names?

Comment: as simple as putting all of them into `[]` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uDoRrfbXEcr)

Comment: are the pizza types fixed

Comment: Yep. The pizza types are fixed. I am going to try ray's variant.